# Discord.NET If a message has a file attached wait until it's uploaded and delete it

Tags: c#, discord.net

My problem is this; I'm making a bot with Discord.NET 1.0.2 that when a user sends a message, check if there is a file attached to that message and then remove it.
Now I made it, but there is one issue with that. The message won't be deleted until the file was uploaded. I have tried various ways but I can't come up with a solution to how I can wait until the file is uploaded, and then delete the message.
Any help is greatly appreciated.
This is what I'm working with:

```
private async Task CheckForImageMessage(SocketMessage s)
{
        var msg = s as SocketUserMessage;
        if (msg == null) return;
        var context = new SocketCommandContext(_client, msg);
        if (context.Message.Attachments.ElementAt(0) != null)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you are not making a command, so there is very little reason for you to be using a command context at all - message is already accessible to you as `s` (`Attachments` collection exists under the `IMessage` interface).

Second, you can't possibly intercept messages before the file is uploaded. If I understood correctly, you wish to delete any messages with attachments included? If so, an [Any](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.any) method on the `Attachments` collection would do.

```
private async Task RemoveAttachmentMsgsAsync(SocketMessage msg)
{
    // check if the source channel is a message channel in a guild
    if (msg.Channel is SocketTextChannel textChannel)
    {
        // get the current user to check for permissions
        var currentUser = textChannel.Guild.CurrentUser;
        // bail if the bot does not have manage message permission
        if (!currentUser.GetPermissions(textChannel).ManageMessages) return;
    }
    // if we made it this far, we can assume that the bot has permission for
    // the channel (including DM channel)
    // use LINQ Any to check if the attachment contains anything
    if (msg.Attachments.Any())
        await msg.DeleteAsync();
}
```

Comment: There is one problem with this, and it is that I'm subscribing this event to the MessageReceived delegate, so once the message is received, the file was not uploaded and I can't remove the message until it is. That is why I needed to check when the file is uploaded and then remove it.

Comment: What do you mean? A message cannot be received when the message has not even been sent. How do you expect Discord's WebSocket to deliver something that they haven't even received?